# getting a program to return immediately at the command line so it's not tied to the shell that launched it

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, process, return

Some programs return immediately when launched from the command line, Firefox for example. Most utilities (and all the programs I've written) are tied to the shell that created them. If you control-c the command line, the program's dead.

What do you have to add to a program or a shell script to get the return-immediately behavior? I guess I'm asking two questions there, one for shell scripts and one for general, if they're different. I would be particularly interested to know if there's a way to get an executable jar to do it.

I'm almost embarrassed to ask that one but I can't find the answer myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116701/how-can-a-c-c-program-put-itself-into-background (from http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unix+background) and possibly also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/what-is-the-reason-for-performing-a-double-fork-when-creating-a-daemon (from http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=daemon+fork+exec+unix which seems to require already knowing part of the answer).

Comment: Good candidate for *not* deleting BTW. This title is a natural expression that will search differently than the others...

Comment: for windows (since google took me here) http://betterlogic.com/roger/2014/01/windows-how-to-start-command-and-have-it-not-use-up-the-command-prompt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an executable program (as opposed to a shell script), on Linux/Unix use fork() and exec() and then exit the parent process, which will return to the shell.  For details see the man pages, or some page like http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html.

Comment: thank you! And Dennis too. It seems like nohup and fork/exec are the answers I was looking for.

Comment: see also the daemon() call which will make it a true background process (detach from the tty and create a new session)

Answer (score 8):

```
start cmd
```

on Windows,

```
cmd &
```

on *nux

Here substitute

```
cmd = java -jar JarFile.jar
```

On *nux the **fg** and **bg** commands are your friends as well ...

Comment: Thanks for the info. Doesn't & just put the process in the background? When I close the terminal emulator the process still dies.

Comment: As Dennis said, nohup is your friend. Then kill by pid using top etc.

Answer (score 4):

You need to basically need to fork a process or create a new thread (or pretend to)

in *nux you can do this with an `&` after the command like this `/long/script &` or in windows you can create a BATCH file that executes your processes then exits (it does this naturally).

NOTE: there's no particularly good way to reference this process after you're forked it, basically only `ps` for the process list.  if you want to be able to see what the process is doing, check out using `screen` (another linux command) that will start a session for you and let you "re-attach" to the screen.

to do this, install screen (`sudo apt-get install screen` or `yum install screen`).  then type `screen` to create a new session (note, it will look like you didn't do anything).  then, run your `/long/command` (without the `&`), then press `CTRL + A + D` (at the same time) to detach from it (it's still running!).  then, when you want to re-attach, type `screen -r`.

Additionally, look for flags in any help message that allow you do this without using the above options (for instance in `synergy` you can say `synergy --background`)

Answer (score 3):

A wrapper script consisting of nothing but:

```
your_prog_or_script &
```

Will launch the target and exit immediately. You can add `nohup` to the beginning of that line so it will continue running if the shell is exited.