# Writing a C program to move a process to background

Tags: c, linux, process, background-process

I am trying to write a program , which does a `fork` and `exec` a child process and executes it in the back ground .

One approach I would see is to redirect the output to `/dev/NULL` file and come back to my main program . Any other ideas ?

Comment: When asking questions, please provide a specific example of what you're trying to achieve and also what you've currently done. In its current state, your question can't really be answered and may be closed. To learn more about asking great questions, see How to Ask- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.

Comment: I am creating my own shell which mimics the behavior of linux shells . Here i want to implement '&' - which runs the process in the background. Hope it gives better insight to my problem

Comment: @Srikanth: I would suggest editing that into your question, and reconciling it with what's there. (Most shells do not redirect output with `&`.)

Comment: @Srikanth You can look this website:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116701/how-can-a-c-c-program-put-itself-into-background

Comment: @Srikanth - I can't figure out what you want. Please edit your question.

Comment: I am creating my own shell which mimics the behavior of linux shells . Here i want to implement '&' - which runs the process in the background. Hope it gives better insight to my problem

Answer (score 0):

After a process is started, shell has no more control on process file descriptors so you can not silence it by a shell command i.e. terminal has its stdin, stdout and stderr bound to the terminal and you cannot do anything about it without re-gaining control over that terminal.

There is a tool called `retty` how you can use it can be seen at this link [retty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin/593764#593764)  this tool is used to attach processes running on terminals

Beside you can also use the built in `disown` command to disown the process which will prevent from sending a `SIGHUP` signal to the program when the shell exits

This link can be helpful [Link to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin/593764#593764)

Comment: Thanks , But i am just curios to know how a "fg " works when you say shell has no more control on process ?

Comment: Please read properly @Srikanth i said process file descriptors. while `bg fg kill` are control commands which no one can stop you from using